# How do we get info for dropped direct messages in Solace due to no subscribers for the message topic?

Tags: solace

I have a pair of Solace appliances setup using MNR, one for DMZ and one for App Zone.  My server is connecting to Solace at App Zone using JCSMP while my client is using MQTT to connect to Solace at DMZ.  Before publishing message to a topic which my client subscribes to (e.g. request/status), my server subscribes to a returned message topic (e.g. returned/status).  Upon receiving the message, my client publishes the response to returned/status.  Sometimes the response fails to reach my server.

I am suspecting this could be due to my server's subscription for returned/status topic may not be replicated in time from Solace at App Zone to Solace at DMZ.  Is there a way to tell that this actually happens?  One way I can think of is to get info on what topics to which messages published to are being dropped, what time this happen and how many messages are dropped for this topic.  Is there a way to get this info from Solace logs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify if this is occurring by checking the no-subscription-match log on the DMZ zone appliance. By running "show log no-subscription-match" in the CLI, you can see when a client published a message that could not be delivered to the client because there were no matching subscriptions.

It is likely that the subscription for the returned/status topic is not being propagated to the neighbor router in time. To get around this issue, it's recommended to always use #P2P inbox topic subscriptions for request/reply messaging over MNR. This is a subscription that is automatically registered for each client upon connect, and gets cleaned up after each disconnect. The router will inject a covering set subscription for the #P2P subscriptions as soon as the neighbor link comes up so that you do not have to wait for the subscription to be propagated.

More information about the P2P inbox subscription is available in the Solace docs:
https://docs.solace.com/Solace-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Publishing-Messages-that.htm